# Android (Java) - Layout is getting cut off at the edges

Tags: java, android, mobile, layout, crop

I'm pretty new to Android Studio so this might be a simple Solution (i hope).

I got this Detail View of an Item but even though the Layout Width and Height are set on "match_parent" it doesn't fit the Screen of my Phone. It does not matter which Layout or .xml I use it is still cropped (linear, relative, constraint), so I guess its something in the code.

[image: picture of the cropped layout]

And heres the Code where i think the Problem is:

```
    public class RecyclerViewAdapterBiography extends RecyclerView.Adapter < RecyclerViewAdapterBiography.MyViewHolder > {

    private Context myContext;
    private List < TimeStamp > myData;
    private Dialog myDialog;

    public RecyclerViewAdapterBiography(Context myContext, List < TimeStamp > myData) {
        this.myContext = myContext;
        this.myData = myData;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View v;
        v = LayoutInflater.from(myContext).inflate(R.layout.biography_item, parent, false);
        final MyViewHolder viewHolder = new MyViewHolder(v);

        // Detail View of the Biography TimeStamps


        // makes the background of the dialog box transparent
        // myDialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));

        // OnClickListener for the different Items in the View (to see the detail view)
        viewHolder.biography_item_id.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                myDialog = new Dialog(myContext);
                myDialog.setContentView(R.layout.biography_detail);

                TextView tv_dialog_title = (TextView) myDialog.findViewById(R.id.bio_details_title);
                TextView tv_dialog_text = (TextView) myDialog.findViewById(R.id.bio_details_desc);

                tv_dialog_title.setText(myData.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getTitle());
                tv_dialog_text.setText(myData.get(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getDialog());

                /*
                Toast.makeText(myContext,"Test Click" + String.valueOf
                        (viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                 */

                myDialog.show();

            }
        });

        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.tv_year.setText(myData.get(position).getYear());
        holder.tv_title.setText(myData.get(position).getTitle());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return myData.size();
    }


    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private LinearLayout biography_item_id;
        private TextView tv_year;
        private TextView tv_title;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            biography_item_id = (LinearLayout) itemView.findViewById(R.id.biography_item_id);
            tv_year = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.biography_year);
            tv_title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.biography_title);

        }
    }
}

<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#fcfcfc">

<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="125dp"
            android:layout_height="175dp"
            android:background="#2d2d2d"
            android:id="@+id/item_biography_img"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Title"
            android:id="@+id/bio_details_title"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bio_details_desc"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="Description" />


    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

I basically tried everything and rn I'm just a/b with stuff I found on the internet to solve this problem, but I can't find any solution

Answer (score 1):

`Dialog`s are meant to be like that - they pop up over your app content, only take up part of the screen, and you can't interact with the rest of the app when they're displayed.

Best take a look at [the docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs) - like it says you're not really meant to use the `Dialog` class directly, the common way is to use an `AlertDialog.Builder` and call the setup methods to define the title, buttons etc. One of the methods is [setView()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder#setView(android.view.View)) which is how you can put a custom layout in there, which you can get by inflating a layout first:

```
view = activity.layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.biography_detail, null)
```

Dialogs have their own layout with all the rounded corners and shadowing and such, so when you just do `setContentView` you're replacing all that styling and you generally don't want that!

---

If you don't want that style, or you want more control (like making it full-screen) then you should create a `DialogFragment` - [there's a good guide here](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Using-DialogFragment) (personally I think that site's really useful for overviews of topics)

There's some stuff on full-screen Dialogs near the end - basically a `DialogFragment` works like a `Fragment`, except you implement an `onCreateDialog` method instead of `onCreate`, and that's where you configure the `Dialog` the system has created for you. When you want to show it, you create an instance and use the `FragmentManager` to show it. The first example in the link explains it, so I won't paste it here!